# Using the SVD rather than covariance matrix to calculate eigenfaces

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, svd

I'm using the set of n = 40 faces from AT&T (http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/facedatabase.html) to try and generate eigenfaces via the SVD.

First I calculate the average vector:

[image: average]

Then I subtract it from every vector in the training set, reshape the new vector into a 1 by (p*q) column vector of a n by (p*q) matrix x, and calculate a matrix X such that `X = (1/sqrt(n))*x`. (here's where the issue is: all my results in X are rounded to 0, resulting in a black image result for eigenface as seen below)

Then I calculate the SVD of this matrix X and try to get the first eigenface of the first column of the unitary matrix by reshaping it back into a p by q matrix

However, this is my result:

[image: eigenface 1]

Can anyone spot my error in the code below? Any answer is much appreciated

```
n = 40;
%read images
A = double(imread('faces_training/1.pgm'));
f(:, :, 1) = A;
for j = 2:n
    f(:, :, j) = double(imread(['faces_training/',num2str(j),'.pgm']));
    A = A + f(:, :, j);
end
%calculate average
a = (1/n)*A;
%imshow(uint8(a))
for i = 1:n
%subtract from images
    x_vector(:, i) = reshape(f(:, :, i) - a, [], 1);
end
X = (1/sqrt(n))*x_vector;
%svd
[U S V] = svd(X);
B = reshape(U(:, 1), [size(a, 1) size(a, 2)]);
imshow(uint8(B))
```

Comment: Does it work with `imshow(B)` instead of `imshow(uint8(B))`?

Comment: No, because B is basically just an array of doubles < 1, so it ends up with the same black image

Comment: If it's an array of doubles between 0 and 1 you shouldn't apply `uint8` because you'll get all zeros. Either `imshow(B)` or `imshow(uint8(255*B))` should work

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified. Each double is significantly smaller than 1 (in fact, the max value in the entire vector is 0.0271) so they all end up at 0 anyway. I tried both your code snippets again just to be sure, and yep- they're both black.

Comment: Then it's probably a normalization issue when computing `B`. I've added the image processing tag so you can get more help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing the same thing and had the same problem. The short answer is you have to normalize your eigenvector to get a good image. Before normalizing, you’ll notice your vector values are very close to 0 (probably because of how svd was done) which probably means they’re close to black.

Anyway, use this equation on the eigenvectors you wanna transform:
`newpixel[i,j]=(oldpixel[i,j]-min(oldpixel[:,j]))/(max(oldpixel[:,j])--min(oldpixel[:,j]))`

Comment: Thanks! I can vaguely remember that this was the problem I discovered too- the pixel values were too close to 0 so I had to transform them after the fact. Thanks for the clear and concise answer! (and welcome to SO :)